# Command Line Arguments

Tags: c++, numbers

I'm trying to write a code that outputs the below as an extension to a program that output perfect numbers.
I'm really struggling with the idea of arguments in C++ and need a little guidance so that the program outputs the correct numbers depending on the argument.

Extend the program so that the badness limit can be specified as a second command line argument. For example,
print_perfect_numbers 100 3 should print 2 3 4 6 8 10 16 18 20 28 32 64.

my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void print_perfect_numbers(int n, int b) {
    for(int c = 2; c < n; c++) {

        int t = 1;

        for (int f = 2; f * f < c; f++) {
            if (c % f == 0) {
                t += f + c / f;
            }
        }

        if (c == t) {
            cout << c << " ";
        }

        else if ((c >= 2) && (t >= (c - b)) && (t <= (c + b))) {
            cout << c << " ";
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    print_perfect_numbers(100,0);
    print_perfect_numbers(100,3);
}
```

to add more context, the original code calculated the perfect numbers (numbers that have factors that equal the number ie 6 is perfect as its factors add up to it 1 + 2 + 3 = 6) up to 100. Quite Good numbers have a badness of a specified value (for the code im writing it is 3) where the factors of a number can equal the original number + or - the badness.

I can get the output of the numbers, however I'm trying to gain separate outputs as arguments for perfect numbers and quite good numbers up to 100.

my output currently is 6 28 2 3 4 6 8 10 18 20 28 32.
i need to make it so the code outputs:
6 28
2 3 4 6 8 10 18 20 28 32
and no, a cout << endl; wont suffice.

pls help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does int argc, char \*argv\[\] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

Comment: I can't really understand what should the function do, you should write a better explanation of the problem.

Comment: Show us your code output, Then we can help you better

Comment: edited for more context as well as current output, thanks.

Comment: more context for output if this helps, testing it against values as arguments
```Failed test 0: differences in output
arguments 
100
expected stdout
6 28
observed stdout
6 28 
2 3 4 6 8 10 18 20 28 32 
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to know is that:

1. `argc` is the number of command line arguments received by the program, that includes ***the name*** of the program for all current OS, meaning, `argc >= 1`, and you should ignore the first argument in `argv`.
2. `argv` is an array of all the arguments passed in console, *as strings* (char* and not std::string!)

In order to get the input, you should parse the second and third arguments of `argv`, if passed. Notice, that you are getting strings and not integers, therefore, you need to parse them into integers, using the following code (assuming the usage is `./program <badness_factor> <upper_bound>`:

```
    uint64_t upper_bound = 100;
    uint64_t badness_factor = 0;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        badness_factor = std::stoul(argv[1]);
        if (argc > 2)
        {
            upper_bound = std::stoul(argv[2]);
        }    
    }
```

Also, I have made some changes to your code, making it more readable, because the code currently isn't!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

bool is_quite_perfect(uint64_t number, uint64_t badness_factor)
{
    uint64_t divisor_sum = 1;

    for (uint64_t divisor = 2; divisor * divisor < number; ++divisor) 
    {
        if (number % divisor == 0)
        {
            uint64_t corresponding_divisor = number / divisor;
            divisor_sum += divisor + corresponding_divisor;
        }
    }

    return (number == divisor_sum) ||  
            (divisor_sum >= (number - badness_factor)) 
             && (divisor_sum <= (number + badness_factor));
}

void print_quite_perfect_numbers(uint64_t upper_bound, uint64_t badness_factor) 
{
    for(uint64_t num = 2; num < upper_bound; ++num) 
    {
        if (is_quite_perfect(num, badness_factor))
        {
            std::cout << num << " ";
        }        
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    uint64_t upper_bound = 100;
    uint64_t badness_factor = 0;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        badness_factor = std::stoul(argv[1]);
        if (argc > 2)
        {
            upper_bound = std::stoul(argv[2]);
        }    
    }

    print_quite_perfect_numbers(upper_bound, badness_factor);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, I think i'm starting to wrap my head around it!